# Event A occurs with probability 0.335. Event B occurs with probability 0.605. Events A and B are mutually exclusive.

Tags: statistics

a.) P (A intersect B)
b.) P (A union B)

So for a, is it true that the probability A intersect B is equal to the probability of A multiplied by the probability of B? Thus, it should be 0.202.. but somehow I'm getting the answer incorrect (even with rounding 0.203).

Then for b, it should be the probability of A plus the probability of B subtracted by the probability of the intersection. So, (0.335+0.605)-0.202 which because 0.202 is somehow incorrect, this answer is also incorrect..

What am I missing? I'm using the formula.

Comment: How do you know it is incorrect? What's the correct answer?

Comment: *"So for a, is it true that the probability A intersect B is equal to the probability of A multiplied by the probability of B?"*

No, that would be if $A$ and $B$ were independent. However, they are not, they are *mutually exclusive*, which means they *can't* both happen: $P(A\cap B)=0$